# Google Compute: Weird error on moving VM instance to different region

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Since my Google Compute VM instance randomly stopped working because the current region "does not have enough resources available", I rationally decided to move my VM instance away from the probable high-load zone `us-eats1-b`, to `us-central1-c`.

I used the following code,

```
gcloud compute disks move my-instance --zone us-east1-b --destination-zone us-central1-c
```

, but get the following weird error, which does not seem to have any resources explaining it anywhere,

```
The disk resource 'projects/project-name/zones/us-east1-b/disks/instance-2' is already being used by 'projects/secure-pillar-235900/zones/u
s-east1-b/instances/project-name'
```

Would someone please help me understand and fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

Disks move is [between zones](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/move) the *same* region. To move across regions, create new instances from images, either public or custom based off the old disk.

You can also create snapshots of your disk and create new instances in the region/zone desired.

Comment: So, in that case, I tried to keep it in the same zone, and did `gcloud compute disks move instance-2 --zone us-east1-b --destination-zone us-east1-d`, but got the same error. Could you tell me what that means then?